# Are the terms in the inclusion exclusion principle monotonic?

Tags: combinatorics, inclusion-exclusion

When doing the inclusion-exclusion principle, there are $n$ sets $A_1,\dots,A_n$, and we compute the sums of all $k$-ways intersections of these sets. Namely, for each $k\in \{1,\dots,n\}$, we compute
$$
S_k=\sum_{i_1<\dots<i_k} |A_{i_1}\cap \dots \cap A_{i_k}|
$$
The size of the union is then $S_1-S_2+S_3-\dots+(-1)^{n-1}S_n$. My question:

> Is it always true that $S_1\ge S_2 \ge \dots \ge S_n$?

This seems to be true in practice. For example, if the universe is the set of permutations of an $n$-element set, and $A_i$ is the set of permutations which fix the $i^\text{th}$ element, then
$$
S_k=\binom nk \cdot (n-k)!=\frac{n!}{k!},
$$
which is clearly weakly decreasing as a function of $k$.

Comment: I am unfamiliar with the syntax that you are using.  In general, suppose that you have the finite sets $S_1, S_2, \cdots, S_r$ and you compute $|S_1 \cup \cdots \cup S_r|$ as $$\sum_{k=1}^r (-1)^{k+1}T_k,$$ where $T_k$ represents the summation of the $~\displaystyle \binom{r}{k}~$ terms, represented as $$\sum_{1 \leq i_1 < \cdots < i_k \leq r} |S_{i_1} \cap S_{i_2} \cap \cdots \cap S_{i_k}|.$$  What you seem to be asking is whether the sequence $$T_1, T_2, \cdots, T_r,$$ is a strictly **non-increasing** sequence.  ...see next comment

Comment: I could be mistaken.  However, I seem to remember, that in my experience, this assertion is not always true.

Comment: Re my previous comments, the intuition is pulling in opposite directions.  For example, when examining $T_1$ versus $T_2$, you are examining $~\displaystyle \binom{r}{1}~$ terms versus $~\displaystyle \binom{r}{2}~$ terms.  On the other hand, each individual term involved in the computation of $T_1$ is **automatically** $~\geq~$ **corresponding** terms in the computation of $T_2$.  For example, clearly, $$|S_1| \geq |S_1 \cap S_2|.$$  Considerations as you go from $T_2$ to $T_3$ and $T_3$ to $T_4$ are similar. ...see next comment

Comment: From the previous comment, since $~\displaystyle \binom{r}{k}~$ will generally be larger than $~\displaystyle \binom{r}{k+1},~$ whenever $k \geq \dfrac{r}{2}$, you **can validly infer** that the **back half** of the sequential elements  $~T_k, T_{k+1}, \cdots, T_{r}~$ are strictly decreasing.

Answer (score 1):

These terms are definitely not decreasing in general. For a simple counterexample, consider when $A_1=\cdots=A_n=A$ is the entire set.